# Multi-line UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

For a modal dialogue, i would like to have a UINavigationBar with a smaller description of the task, followed by a traditional UINavigationBar - this is the style seen in many of the system apps on iOS.

What is the best way to achieve this?

To see what I mean, see these example screenshots from Maps and Contacts (I choose the iOS6 screenshots, because having the standard gradient expand is also something which I would like to have).

[image: Maps choose bookmark]

[image: Contacts add favourites screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen shots you posted are using the `UINavigationItem prompt` property.

In your view controller you can do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Some message to appear at the top";
    self.title = @"Some Title";
}
```